# Print the return of a method

Tags: perl

I know in php I can do something like this

```
echo "{$this->method}";
```

and I swear there was a way to do it in perl

**Update:**
What I am trying to do is print a scalar that the method returns. I was kind of hoping of doing within the string like in php, just because I'm lazy :P.

Comment: `${this->method}`, if my long-rusty perl memories are bubbling to the surface correctly.

Comment: Tried that, throws an error. this is looked up as a module or package

Comment: Have you considered using `printf`? I often found this to be the most readable, especially when there are many interpolations in a single string.

Comment: I completely forgot about `printf`. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you just trying to evaluate an arbitrary expression inside a double quoted string? Then maybe you're thinking of

```
print "@{[$this->method]}";
```

There is also a trick to call the method in scalar context, but the syntax is a little less clean.

```
print "${\($this->method)}";
```

Comment: Out of mere curiosity, does that create a throw away array or is it optimised?

Comment: How is this feature called and where is it documented? Or is it something that returns an array reference and then dereferences it?

Comment: In [`perlref`, the end of the section "Using References"](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlref#Using_References). The only reference to a name in the doc is "chicanery".  ;-)

Comment: -1:  The OP has given us no indication as to what type of output is returned by the method.

Comment: @Blagovest Buyukliev, Yes, all of anonymous array construction, array dereference and array interpolation are documented.

Comment: @NebulaFox, it's not optimised.

Comment: @mob, your post falsely implies `print "@{[$this->method]}";` doesn't work for scalars. I hope you don't mind that I changed the phrasing.

Comment: @Jack Maney, You -1 the wrong post. If the OP didn't give enough info, than he's the one that made the mistake, not the one that gave a good answer for the info given.

Comment: @NebulaFox, I did say "*If* the OP ..."

Comment: @ikegami I was just pointing it out. Should of put a [at]Jack

Comment: \ doesn't provide scalar context to the method; the method will be called in list context and \ will produce a reference to each element in the list returned; then `${}` will use the last of those.

Comment: note that because the first step in perl's parsing a string is finding the end delimiter, if you use the delimiter in that code, it must be \-escaped: `"@{[$this->method_given_a_quote('\"')]}"`.  Here, the \ is removed before the code is even parsed (though other \ in the inlined code are not tampered with).

Comment: Can somebody PLEASE explain to me why this is useful (outside of golfing)?

Comment: @DVK - useful for dumping the contents of a hash. Compare `print "hash=@{[%hash]}"` with `print "hash=",join" ",%hash`

Comment: @Socket - Hmm... I see where you coud argue that. Though wouldn't `print Dump([\%hash])` using `Data::Dumper` be a better fit for that purpose than either of those 2 approaches?

Answer (score 3):

Well, if `$this->method` outputs a string or a number (like PHP, Perl can automatically convert numbers to strings when required), then you can do `print $this->method . "\n";`.

If `$this->method` outputs a data structure (eg an array reference or a hash reference), you can use [`Data::Dumper`](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.131/Dumper.pm) to look at the structure of the data.  Basically, `print Dumper($foo)` is the Perl equivalent of PHP's `var_dump($foo)`.

What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: I see, so you can't do within the string?

Comment: Can't do **what** within what string?  Describe, in complete sentences in English, what you're trying to do.

Comment: what I'm saying is I want to do this `"$this->method"`, besides doing `"" . $this->method . "\n"` is there someway to do `"$this->method"`

Comment: I still have no idea what you're talking about.  Is the output of `$this->string` a scalar?

Answer (score 1):

If `$this->method` is returning a string, you can do this:

```
print $this->method . "\n";
```

without quotes. That will print your string. Sometimes, that can lead to a clumsy looking statement:

```
print "And we have " . $this->method . " and " . $that->method . " and " . $there->method . "\n";
```

In that case you can use a little programming trick of:

```
print "And we have @{[$this->method]} and @{[that->method]} and @{[$their->method]}\n";
```

Surrounding a function with `@{[]}` prints out the function's value. Someone explained this to me once, but I can't remember why it works.

Comment: Arrays interpolate in double quoted strings, so `@{...}` is interpolated as an array, and all the elements are joined with `$"`.  The `[...]` constructs the array reference that `@{...}` will dereference.  The method call sees list context from within the `[...]`.  It is the same as `my $ref = [$this->method]; "@{$ref}"`

Comment: I knew it had something to do with `[]` being reference to an anonymous array, but I never quite understood why `$ref = [$this->method]` is valid syntax. Why does the anonymous array get the return value of $this->that. But, it works, and that's all my puny brain can understand.

Comment: `$ref = [$this->method]` is the same as `$ref = do {my @a = $this->method; \@a}` just shorter.

Comment: I'd use `printf` or `sprintf` over that "programming trick" any day. It's definitely good to know and may be handy for one interpolation but not for so many (although I still wouldn't use it).

Comment: @musiKk: It comes down to which is easier to understand and maintain. If you think `printf "%s and %s and %s\n", $this->method, $that->method, $other->method` is easier to understand and maintain, use it. I will many times use the `@{[]}` for constants: `say "And pi is equal to @{[PI]}.";` because I think it reads a bit easier.